# Non Decreasing array with GCD greater than 1

Tags: greatest-common-divisor, number-theory

I am given a finite non decreasing arbitrary array. I can add zero or more to the individual elements of the array. What is the minimum additions required to ensure than the gcd of the array is strictly greater than 1? The non decreasing condition should hold.

Answer (score -1):

Well the trivial thing to do is:

- Check the `gcd()` of the array is actually 1. If it's bigger you're done already.
- Otherwise round up numbers until they are even. This will not break the order of elements (i.e. the non-descreasing property will continue to hold once you are done with the entire array in this way).
- Et Voilà: the `gcd()` of the array is now at least 2.

Number of additions performed:

- Best case scenario: zero additions.
- Worst case scenario: length(array) additions.
- Average case, based on 50% chance of element being odd: ceil(0.5 * length(array)) additions.

Comment: but for array=>(5,15,19) answer must be 1, but acc. to your approach. it should be three

Comment: Oh yes. Notice: I said trivial, not "optimal", there's plenty more cases like that. Since this is clearly a Math homework problem and OP hasn't bothered to state what has been tried/rejected already... I figured I'd give a starting point rather than try to solve it entirely.